# Method Not Allowed (GET): /cart/add/1/

Tags: django

I have a problem with allow method GET in my project, I find out problem but nothing working.
I try everything, but nothing working, the messages in my postman is
{Method Not Allowed (GET): /cart/add/1/}
Please help me how to solve this problem?

cart/view

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    print('privet')
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})

cart/url
  path('', cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', cart_remove, name='cart_remove')

shop/view

def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = Product.objects.filter(id=id, slug=slug)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'web/catalog.html', {'product': product,
                                                'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})


shop/detail.html

                          <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ cart_product_form.as_p }}
                                {{ cart_product_form.non_field_errors }}
                                <div class="Card-hover">
                                    <a class="Card-btn" href="{% url 'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" type="submit" value='add to cart'><img
                                            src="{% static 'img/icons/card/cart.svg' %}" alt="cart.svg"/></a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be replace @require_POST to @require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
It will allow get & post both methods.

Comment: I've changed. but now it is not added to the cart. url automatically changes from

[25/Feb/2023 11:46:03] "GET /cart/add/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0.  on 
[25/Feb/2023 11:46:03] "GET /cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22111

Comment: I added to
 return redirect('cart:cart_detail', product_id)
product_id , but then it shows this error Reverse for 'cart_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/\\Z']. I can't figure out why this is an error please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `require_POST()` decorator means that you require the view to accept only the POST method. Try changing it to `require_GET()` so that you only accept the GET method, or you can list the allowed methods with `@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])` and allow both the GET and POST methods.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/decorators/) I attach an article from the documentation.

Comment: I've changed. but now it is not added to the cart. url automatically changes from [25/Feb/2023 11:46:03] "GET /cart/add/1/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0. on [25/Feb/2023 11:46:03] "GET /cart/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22111

Comment: i added to
 return redirect('cart:cart_detail', product_id)
product_id , but then it shows this error Reverse for 'cart_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/\\Z']. I can't figure out why this is an error please help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the indentation in the CART class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).